# IBM MobileFirst direct update and security tets

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using the IBM MobileFirst studio plugin 7.0 and following the documentation here:[Link to documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-quickly-update-application/) on how to configure a direct update. I’m trying to understand how the pieces work together but I am not able to grasp the concept.

Using the code sample that is provided along with the tutorial, I see that  the "mobileSecurityTest" is commented out and the "customSecurityTest" element  present is also commented out.

Another thing I noticed is that in that application-descriptor.xml, there  is no security test  for the added environments?

1. How will the application know which securityTest to use at the app level app?
2. Does the securityTest need to be placed on the environment in general and specifically for a direct update?
3. The direct update wasn't getting triggered when running the sample and following the instructions on the app

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your application descriptor and your authentication config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You specify what security test you want to use in the application-descriptor of you app.

Inside my application descriptor I have an iPhone app with customSecurityTest:

```
<iphone bundleId="com.PhoneUp" version="1.0" securityTest="customSecurityTests">
    <worklightSettings include="false"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
    </security>
</iphone>
```

Inside my authentication config I have:

```
<customSecurityTest name="customSecurityTests">
    <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
    <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
    <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
    <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
    <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
    <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

Now the security test that is protecting my application has a mapping to the security test in my authentication-config (security file on the server)

2. No a security test does not need to be placed on the application to trigger a direct update.
   You may trigger the direct update just by the user trying to "login" to that realm.

   ```
   WL.Client.login("wl_directUpdateRealm", {onSuccess:..., onFailure:...});
   ```

   Direct update is a realm you can read more about that [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_direct_update_as_security_realm.html?lang=en).
3. The sample project from [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-quickly-update-application/) does not have the security test commented in or a security test protecting the application. You are going to have to uncomment and add a security test in your appliation descriptor as described in the answer to number one.

Comment: Thank you this has helped tremendously. Just a note that these snippets you have provided do not reflect in the sample and it can be very confusing